# test containers testing in spring s3 service errors

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, testcontainers

I have set up s3 container, and have a basic test working. What i wanted to know was how can i test it throws AwsServiceException. Is there anyway i can get the container to do that.

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class TestContainerSetUp {

    protected static final String BUCKET_NAME = "testbucket";

    @Container
    public static final S3MockContainer s3MockContainer = new S3MockContainer(DockerImageName.parse("adobe/s3mock:2.4.13"))
            .withInitialBuckets(BUCKET_NAME);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Testcontainers ToxiProxy module](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/toxiproxy/) can be used here. See an example [here](https://github.com/eddumelendez/testcontainers-samples/blob/main/spring-boot-r2dbc-postgresql-chaos/src/test/java/com/example/springbootr2dbcpostgresqlchaos/SpringBootR2dbcPostgresqlChaosApplicationTests.java#L41-L46). Client should point to the proxy created via toxiproxy and then you can simulate timeouts, latency, and soon. Read more about toxiproxy [here](https://github.com/Shopify/toxiproxy).